# Jenkins pipeline "git push" fails on a Windows build node?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, git-for-windows

I wrote a simple pipeline to test for Git access

```
node("windows-build-node") {
    dir(env.WORKSPACE) {
        stage("clone") {
            sh "whoami"
            git url: "git@bitbucket.org:company/someRepo.git",
                branch: "development",
                credentialsId: "bb-ssh"
        }

        stage("Create and push branch") {
            sh """
                git checkout development
                git checkout -b feature/test-branch-access
                git push origin feature/test-branch-access
            """
        }
        
        stage("Test delete") {
            sh" git push origin feature/test-branch-access --delete"
        }
    }
}
```

and I get

```
17:34:27  + whoami
17:34:27  SYSTEM
...
17:34:33  + git push origin feature/test-branch-access
17:34:33  Host key verification failed.
17:34:33  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
17:34:33  
17:34:33  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
17:34:33  and the repository exists.
```

Where is the `known_hosts` file in Windows so I can add the host key for our Bitbucket server?

Comment: This looks more like an issue with the RSA key credentials. If you have credentials already setup in Jenkins (I see `bb-ssh`), then you can try https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/ with the `gitUsernamePassword` binding.

Comment: No, we us ssh credentials, which set up to be password-less, and the ssh keys work, otherwise the clone would've failed.

Comment: Ok right, so you would use those bindings instead and then this will work for you, and you also glean the other advantages as well.

Comment: And that's what bugs me, how come the clone works, but not the push?

Comment: The clone is part of a class utilizing the credentials plugin with the appropriate id. The push is part of a shell step method with no associated credentials. That is why my suggestion will likely solve the issue for you.